# Warning: React does not recognize the `pId` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, warnings

When I comment the span tag given below then it doesn't show any warning.

```
<span onClick={onCommentClick} className={'comment'}>
                        <AiOutlineComment className={"i"} size={"20px"}/> Comment
                    </span>
```

But, if I don't comment and include in file then it says

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `pId` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `pid` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in path (created by AiOutlineComment)
    in svg (created by Context.Consumer)
    in IconBase (created by AiOutlineComment)
    in AiOutlineComment (at Posts.jsx:79)
    .........
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:10)
```

But i haven't passed any props such as pId. What it is saying.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {AiOutlineDislike, AiOutlineLike, AiFillCaretDown, AiFillDelete, AiOutlineComment} from "react-icons/all";
import {like, unlike} from "../../redux/post/postActions";
import {connect, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {deletePost} from '../../redux/post/postActions'
import Moment from 'react-moment'
import {fetchProfile} from "../../redux/profile/profileActions";
import CommentForm from "./comments/CommentForm";
import Comments from "./comments/Comments";

const Posts = ({post, like, unlike, deletePost, fetchProfile}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProfile();
    }, [fetchProfile]);
    const {auth, profile} = useSelector(state=>state)
    const onLike = (e, id) => {
        // e.preventDefault()
        like(id)
    }

    const onUnlike = (e, id) => {
        // e.preventDefault()
        unlike(id)
    }

    const [boxDropdown, setBoxDropdown] = useState(false)

    const onClick = () => {
        setBoxDropdown(!boxDropdown)
    }

    const delPost = (e,id) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        deletePost(id)
    }

    const [showComment, setShowComment] = useState(false)

    const onCommentClick = () => {
        setShowComment(!showComment)
    }

    return (
        <div className="posts">
            <div className="box-header">
                <AiFillCaretDown onClick={onClick} className={"i dropdown-i"} size={"20px"}/>
                {
                    boxDropdown &&
                    <div className={"box-dropdown"}>
                        <ul>
                            {
                                auth.user._id === post.user &&
                                <li onClick={(e)=>delPost(e, post._id)}><AiFillDelete className={"i"} size={"20px"}/>Delete</li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                }
                <img className={"small-image"} src={profile.profile.image !== null
                && profile.profile.image !== undefined
                && profile.profile.image !== ""
                && post.user === auth.user._id
                    ?
                    profile.profile.image
                    :`${post.avatar}`} alt="avatar"/>
                <div>
                    <h5>{post.name}</h5>
                    <span><Moment fromNow>{post.date}</Moment></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>{post.text}</p>
            <div className="box-footer">
                    <span onClick={(e)=>onLike(e, post._id)} className={"like"}>
                        <AiOutlineLike className={"i"} size={"20px"}/> {post.likes.length}
                    </span>
                <span onClick={(e)=>onUnlike(e, post._id)} className={"dislike"}>
                        <AiOutlineDislike className={"i"} size={"20px"}/> {post.unlikes.length}
                    </span>
                <span onClick={onCommentClick} className={'comment'}>
                        <AiOutlineComment className={"i"} size={"20px"}/> Comment
                    </span>
            </div>

            {/*<CommentForm post={post} showComment={showComment} />*/}
            <Comments />
        </div>
    )
}

export default connect(null, {like, unlike, deletePost, fetchProfile})(Posts)
```

Comment: It's clearly an issue in the react-icons library. https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/issues/344

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because of `Ai` icons from `react-icons`. I fixed this problem using other icons like `Fa` icons. Check out this [issue](https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form/pull/2046) from Github.

Example:

```js
<FaRegCommentDots size={25} />
```